# Was Larry Bird the first basketball player to wipe his sneakers during games?

Tags: basketball, nba

Players wiping their sneakers during deadball periods is ubiquitous now.  I remember hearing somewhere that Larry Bird started doing it, but not for any particular reason.

Is he the first to make this action during a game?  Was there another player to have done it sooner?

Comment: I've deleted the image here - please don't add images which are not available under a CC-BY-SA license or under fair use.